# Aws json policy - Error: Parse error on line 10

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Staring at this but can't figure out what's the error, Trying to give user (in principle) access to bucket mentioned in resource.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::000000:user/username"
            
            }
            },
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Error: Parse error on line 10:
...         }       },      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],

Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'

edited a few times but no luck, new to this.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra `}` below the line `"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::000000:user/username"`. Please find the fixed json below.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement":
    [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal":
            {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::000000:user/username"
            },
            "Action":
            [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        }
    ]
}
```